# Where is the appropriate place to ask questions related to Vim?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I had a question regarding how to do some specific thing in [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and a good way to do it, either through a plugin or through a command that already exists. Therefore, I was wondering whether this was an appropriate question for Stack Overflow or any of its related sites.

---

After reading the responses I believe the best place is Stack Overflow since my question is specifically useful for coding, but I will still post the GIST of it, just in case I am wrong and it might belong better on another site.

The GIST of the question I want to ask:

I am used to programming in [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text). In Sublime Text I can select a sequence of characters and the editor will automatically highlight any other sequence of characters on my screen. I am not actually looking for something that does **exactly** the same as Sublime Text, but either something similar or something I can change at my own liking. Maybe some key shortcut in visual mode after I have selected something that will highlight or cycle through the sequence of characters would be a good starting point.

Currently what I am doing is the search command `/` and the manually typing the sequence I am looking for.

Comment: If the question you have relates to an aspect of using it for programming then it would be appropriate on SO. Otherwise, you would want to try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/about)

Comment: Some questions can be on-topic on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as well.

Comment: If you tell us what the "specific thing" is you want to do (not a long explanation but the gist of it) then we can give you a better idea of where to take it. Otherwise, read the help center about what types of questions are appropriate at each of the recommended sites and you can make an informed decision. And thanks for asking since you are unsure instead of posting where it may not belong.

Comment: I have added the GIST of the question. As a side note, thanks for your post! I really love the exchange sites and I try my best to be a good user for all the sites! Its my way of being grateful for all the help I have gotten over the small amount of time I have been in it. :)

Comment: SuperUser would probably be best (because some people will see this as not fitting the scope of programming tools and it doesn't sound like specific to programming) but SO might be ok as well.

Answer (score 10):

The best place would be [Vi/Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Note that that site is currently in beta.

Answer (score 8):

There is a much longer discussion that was on MSO that has been migrated to MSE on this very subject.

[Vim questions: do they belong to Stack Overflow or Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user)

> In my opinion, it belongs on Stack Overflow. Vi/m is basically a programmer's editor, and configuring it is essentially programming.

Answer (score 4):

Super User is good for general Vim questions.

Unix & Linux is good for more specific Vim platform questions.

Stack Overflow is good for programming-related Vim questions.

Comment: This answer is probably now incomplete given @Lernkurve's answer.