# Merge [google-apps-script-editor] to [google-apps-script]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Up until recently, [the tag usage guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47025188/revisions) of [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) read,

> Use for questions about Google Apps Script Editor which do not involve actual script development issues.

By this definition, Most questions should be off-topic.

Currently it reads,

> Use for questions about Google Apps Script Editor (the web application IDE from Google) not for questions about other IDEs

Unlike other IDEs like [vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode), all [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) code are finally saved and run in the same IDE, even if you can initially develop in any other IDE. Anyone familiar with apps script is also familiar with the default IDE and thus does not need a separate tag and it causes harm by hiding questions from potential answerers.

Propose synonymizing/merging [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) to the main tag [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Community consensus reached. Sub tag [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) synonymized to parent tag [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) by community.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree because...

Stack Overflow scope goes beyond questions directly related to writing code, it also includes questions about tools commonly used by programmers.

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - ## software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But agree that regarding that the tag excerpt/wiki could be improved.

Related

- [Scope of "software tools commonly used by programmers" in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276671/1595451)

Comment: Where in my post did I say software tools/IDE are off-topic?The first definition is vague where it fully excludes any "script development issues".It can be interpreted to exclude debugging,script saving/running or almost anything related to script development,but something exclusive to the editor- say, "How to change the menu button color to black". Even if that can be considered software tools usage, My entire point is: **Anyone familiar with apps script is also familiar with the default IDE and thus does not need a separate tagand it causes harm by hiding questions from potential answerers**

Comment: It looks that you are questioning the current tag excerpt, otherwise what is the point of mentioning to previous one? By the other hand the way to handle tags that causes harm is called "burnination"

Comment: Burninate has special criteria. Causes harm isn't the only criteria.  The point of mentioning of previous  guideline is that, that is the guideline used for 3 years and the latest guideline barely for 1-3 months. You can't judge all the questions in this tag by only looking at  the excerpt that is only been for a few months.

Comment: The root cause of questions "being hidden" from potential answerers isn't this tag. It's very likely that root cause is that the askers of those question don't know how to ask a good question. Anyway, did you know that there are  >4k questions open, without any answers that currently have [tag:google-apps-script]?

Comment: Does this tag offer any advantage over just [tag:google-apps-script] tag?  Why is segregation necessary? If you want debugging or editor related questions, Wouldn't it be easier to just search for [tag:google-apps-script]+ editor?

Comment: @TheMaster This tags is helpful, among other things, to find canonical questions / dup candidates for questions about the GAS editor. Relaying only on [tag:google-apps-script] makes it very hard and is becoming harder and harder as the this tag popularity increases. By the other hand  having this tag makes it possible to share specific resources i.e. bugs / feature requests, canonical questions, etc.

Comment: By the other hand, this tag is an essential part of what I do every "night", "...  try and take over the world!" (https://images.app.goo.gl/9n5eNFKnJr12J86h6) :)

Answer (score -2):

I agree that the tag [google-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-script-editor) *can* be synonymized, as:

1. It is not a major part of the platform (and the new editor based on Monaco is in the works by Google).
2. The useful info from the wiki can be preserved in the main tag wiki page.

Also, some heavyweight tags adopted the same approach of making branching tags synonyms of the main tag:

1. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) with [javascript-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-library), [javascript-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-runtime), and [javascript-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-module)
2. [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) with [php-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-frameworks) and [php-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-cli)
3. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) with [python-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-shell) and [python-interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-interpreter)
4. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) with [java-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-libraries) and [oraclejdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oraclejdk)

---

> The alternative proposal below is not considered anymore, voted for synonymizing. The matter is closed in favor of the original proposal.

---

**Proposal**

Synonymize [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) to [google-apps-script-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-project).

**Reasoning**

There are several tags that represent entities that constitute the structure of a singular Apps Script project (others are: [google-apps-script-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-libraries) and [google-apps-script-dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-dashboard)), en masse map a domain sufficiently different from the broader [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), dealing with script project management, deployment, debugging, associating [Cloud Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project), and going through Google's Oauth [verification process](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) for applications.

This will also help to keep usage guidelines and references to useful resources visible (ideally paired with a canonical Q&A containing detailed info), whereas in the main platform tag they will likely drown under the amount of info there already is.

The scope of the question about [google-apps-script-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-editor) will also be sufficiently described if used like this (but [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) used with the main tag does not entail that it is about the Editor):

[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)[google-apps-script-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-project) and [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) or [web-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-ide)

**References**

1. [Official guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#creating_and_deleting_projects) on Script Projects

Comment: Most actions mentioned like dealing with script project management, verification process are highly unlikely to be considered to be ontopic. Even if they are, they're not about programming and border line super-user category and don't warrant a new tag. Neither is [tag:google-apps-script-menu] or [tag:google-apps-script-dashboard]. Furthermore, none of these branches are recognizable or usable easily by new users. It'll be a retagging mess.   Strongly Disagree. Also against [tag:google-apps-script-project]. Use [tag:google-cloud-platform] or [tag:google-oauth] instead.

Comment: @TheMaster - that's exactly what I propose - either synonymize or merge into a single [tag:google-apps-script-project]. About [tag:google-apps-script-menu] - that's different, I think it should be merged into main too. That said, I disagree that script project issues are off-topic here: also part of the domain is [importing/exporting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/import-export) projects and [tag:clasp] issues

Comment: Also against [tag:google-apps-script-project]. Use with [tag:google-cloud-platform] or [tag:google-oauth] should be sufficient.

Comment: @TheMaster - the problem is that GCP is much broader, it is not a correct substitute for the script project ( in fact, the only part of GCP that is relevant here are default and standard Cloud Projects ). [tag:google-oauth] is also much broader and intersects with [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and [Identity platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth) as a whole

Comment: Why not? Split tags allow for such overlap. I disagree with the notion that all tags should be narrow. *( in fact, the only part of GCP that is relevant here are default and standard Cloud Projects* You're just seeing the initial overlap.. but it can go deeper - say, a shared GCP with another project, that is not even related to apps script.

Comment: The problem I have with it is that [tag:google-apps-script] + [tag:google-cloud-platform] are just two platform tags. Our main tag serves visibility to SMEs well, the other includes a broad spectrum of issues not related to Apps Script at all, the same goes for [tag:google-oauth]. I am not arguing for sub-tagging, but I think 1-2 branches (that represent a domain of issues) should remain.

Comment: Exactly why a separate tag for intersection between two platform tags are unnecessary. There won't be enough questions.  Furthermore SMEs in apps script are not well versed in GCP. The GCP expertise is needed in such situations.A eg would be [tag:javascript]. JS deals with a broad variety of issues, but when tagged with [tag:google-apps-script], they only answer if it's within their expertise and where GAS expertise is lacking.

Comment: I think that `google-apps-script-project` is unnecessary. It's barely used, very loosely defined, and there are better tags which fit it. `google-apps-script-project` should be synonymised to `google-cloud-platform` and `google-apps-script-editor` to `google-apps-script`.

Comment: @TheMaster that's not what I mean at all, quite the opposite - I referred to [tag:google-cloud-platform].  That said, if there existed a [tag:cloud-platform-project] that is a *synonym* of [tag:google-cloud-platform] I might consider switching to [tag:google-apps-script] + [tag:google-cloud-platform] or [tag:logging] or [tag:ide] depending on the situation.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - I think we have a misunderstanding here, Apps Script projects have very little to do with Cloud Platform, and can't be made a synonym. See the whole chapter of official guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#creating_and_deleting_projects

Comment: You're speaking as if [tag:google-apps-script-project] is different from [tag:gcp]. It's not. It's the same thing attached to [tag:google-apps-script].

Comment: @OlegValter Apps Script Projects *are* GCP projects on the backend. If it's not manually tied to a GCP project then it has its own unique identifier anyway. If it's a question not directly related to the GCP side of things then I see no reason for `google-apps-script-project` to not be a synonym of good old `google-apps-script`.

Comment: @TheMaster, I apologize for insisting, but how about a direct quote from docs? "every Apps Script project has an associated Google Cloud Platform project". They are not identical, that said, I do not say they are not intricately connected.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo although I disagree with the notion of them being identical (if they were, you could manage libraries and manifests through GCP directly, also Properties are part of the apps script project that are not available in GCP) and think that the confusion arises due to them being interconnected (especially because one cannot live without another), it is not my intention to hinder the effort - if I am in the minority here, I am ready to accept it as a synonym.

Comment: No need to apologize. @RafaGuillermo makes a good point here. If the question is not about GCP or it's management(do note: If they are, you need 3 looong tags: [tag:google-apps-script],[tag:google-apps-script-project],[tag:google-cloud-platform]), If it's just about *dealing with script project management, deployment, debugging*, The last one should  just be tagged [debugging] or [stackdriver] [logging]. The first 2 uses: Every script is managed. Not every script is deployed, but that alone don't warrant a separate tag. Even if it is deployed, usage  with [-api] or [-web-app] should be enough.

Comment: @TheMaster - I don't *entirely* disagree with the approach, that's why I apologize. That said, I feel compelled to defend the specificity of the domain of apps script projects. On the note of long tags (I think you meant something else, and not two apps script tags, btw :)), I also dislike the long naming, I think it should be referred to as [tag:apps-script-project] or, ideally (but that won't probably happen), [tag:gas-project]. With [tag:logging] there is a problem - all is good when this is [tag:stackdriver], but what if we are talking about basic logging?

Comment: @OlegValter Don't all basic logs go to stackdriver with v8? It is visible in the UI. but that's it. And rhino is no longer a default. We can't be having a tag for every url or every web-page that we visit in apps script and think it's something different and create a tag for it.

Comment: @TheMaster that's true, but they *also* go there, but `Logger` still has its own issues (alongside what is displayed in the execution dashboard). In fact, we've just been discussing a problem very specific to them and newer runtime that still does not have anything to do with Stackdriver. That said, I am hesitant to convert this into a discussion about validity of apps script project itself - it is an alternative proposal after all

Comment: I remember 1 or 2 issues about the logs showing up late or not showing at all. Again, Don't think it warrants a separate tag. Coming back, you're right about script projects vs gcp. . Yes it's in the official doc. But what the public perceives is more important.. I as a gold badge holder couldn't differentiate it just by it's  name(until you clearly said the difference) How will new users or other users think about it?  It's a ambigous tag at best

Comment: @TheMaster - I am talking more as a whole, not individually (that is, counting Libraries + Logging + GCP + Editor). With just logging, it would not be enough, I agree. Anyways, I really do not want it to become a stumbling block, so I will be content with a simple vote in our room, what do you say? I may have more compelling arguments by then.